# Is Scarlet Witch a Strange-level sorceress, or an Omega-level mutant?

Tags: marvel, mutant, scarlet-witch

Looking for a definitive answer here. Originally, Wanda Maximoff's powers were said to "Alter probability to cause various effects." Then, with some study, she was able to use them to tap into naturally occurring "Chaos power", a force of elemental magic from another dimension which fuels supernatural essences, similar to the Dark Force. Considering the far reaching effects of the **House of M** storyline, where she *literally depowered 90% of the mutant populace,* that would (or at least, *should*) put her **easily** in Omega class; it was essentially large-scale, specific-effect reality warping.

It's unclear (to me) if this was an effect of Omega-level mutant power, or some high-level sorcerer. Due to the various ret-cons that have taken place, how her powers work and their origins are also somewhat unclear. With the MCU version not "technically" being seen as a mutant, but having high level psychic and limited energy manipulation ability derived from one of the Infinity Stones, this becomes even more murky. So...

1. Is Wanda still considered a mutant, or a mutate?
2. If she is a mutant, has she been defined *in canon* as Omega-level?
3. Did M-Day happen because of mutant reality warping, or because of magic?

Comment: Your main question is like you’re asking about the main comics continuity but then you mention the MCU which is a different universe. What universe are you asking about?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, both Wanda and Pietro aren't mutants anymore (and actually never were), instead they were revealed to be experiments conducted by the High Evolutionary in *Uncanny Avengers* #4 (2015):

[image: The true origin of the twins is revealed]

In fact, *House of X* #4 (2019) explicitly lists her as a non-mutant:

> LOOK AT WHAT THEY’VE DONE
>
> MUTANT EXTINCTION EVENTS [...]
>
> DECIMATION: MUTANT ERASURE BY **THE PRETENDER WANDA MAXIMOFF** - 1 MILLION DEPOWERED
>
> In addition to the two mutant extinction-level events, recent history has seen an uptick in the incidence of human-on-mutant violence. The increased number of mutant births since [the Lights] has only served to provide more opportunity for these human-on-mutant crimes to be enacted.
>
> A LIST OF HUMANS WHO HAVE COMMITTED MAJOR MUTANT CRIMES [...]
>
> Wanda Maximoff - The Avengers - 986,420

[image: "look at what they've done" insert]

Comment: Pfft. You de-power a million mutants and suddenly you're the bad guy

Comment: Her marvel bio also explicitly lists her as a non-mutant: https://www.marvel.com/characters/scarlet-witch-wanda-maximoff/in-comics

Comment: @Jenayah  So Scarlet Witch's powers come from the high Evolutionary according to Uncanny Avengers #4 (2015):?   I only remember reading the name High Evolutionary once before. In a letters column in a Marvel comic someone mentioned a story and the impression  the ultimate fate of the High Evolutionary made on them, which made me think that the High Evolutionary character was killed off decades before 2015.